# Div elements affected by margin

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and the `<div>` childs are getting affected by the margin when I put it in the parent because I want it to have a space to each other.

I've tried padding but it doesn't do a thing. I know that it has a property of `p-3` `mb-5` which is part of bootstrap 5 but removing it would cause the parent `<div>` to stuck to each other...

https://jsfiddle.net/atog0Lfj/1/

```css
.container{
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: -100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .container-fluid{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block; 
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #mainNav{
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 1s; 
    }
    
    #mainNav.fade{
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .container-sm{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; 
    }
    
    /*TEXTS*/
    .display-2{
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
      
    .regiontext{
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .schooltext{
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .tuitiontext{
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .citytext{
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    /*END OF TEXTS*/
    .selectregion{
      outline: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .selectcity{
      outline: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .selectschool{
      outline: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .region{
      padding: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      display: block; 
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
     
    .city{
      padding-left: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      display: block; 
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    
    .tuition{
      width: 100%;
      display: block; 
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-right: 15px;
      margin-left: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    
    .school{
      width: 100%;
      display: block; 
      margin-right: 15px;
      margin-left: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    
    .selecttuition{
      display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
      outline: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .search{
      margin-top: -30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainNav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    
       <div class="region shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
        <div class="container-sm">
            <h2 class="regiontext"><img src="nav img/region.png"alt="" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-bottom">Region</h2>
          
            <div class="region2">
                <select id="selectreg" class="selectregion">
                  <option value="1">N/A</option>
                  <option value="2">Region I (Ilocos Region)</option>
                  <option value="3">Region II (Cagayan Valley)</option>
                  <option value="4">Region III (Central Luzon)</option>
                  <option value="5">Region IV‑A (CALABARZON)</option>
                  <option value="6">MIMAROPA Region</option>
                  <option value="7">Cordillera Administrative Region (CAR)</option>
                  <option value="8">National Capital Region (NCR)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>

        <div class="city shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
        <div class="container-sm">
          
          <h2 class="citytext"><img src="nav img/city.png"alt="" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-bottom">Cities</h2>
          <div class="city2">
             <select id="selectcity" class="selectcity">
              <option value="3">N/A</option>
              <option value="shs">Senior High School</option>
              <option value="tertiary">Tertiary</option>
             </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="tuition shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
        <div class="container-sm">
          
          <h2 class="tuitiontext"><img src="nav img/cash.png"alt="" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-bottom">Tuition</h2>
          <div class="city2">
             <select id="selecttuition" class="selecttuition">
              <option value="3">N/A</option>
              <option value="shs">Senior High School</option>
              <option value="tertiary">Tertiary</option>
             </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="school shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
        <div class="container-sm">
          
          <h2 class="schooltext"><img src="nav img/university.png"alt="" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-bottom">Schools</h2>
          <div class="school2">
             <select id="selectschool" class="selectschool">
              <option value="shs">Public</option>
              <option value="tertiary">Private</option>
             </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container">
          <div class="search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit"><img src="nav img/search.png" width="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-bottom"></button>
       </div>
    
    
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: On setting up your snippet in codepen, the screen goes white. Can you share an external link to codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: https://imgur.com/kvYX5dR here's my problem as you can see the region div and city div is too close to each other if i put margin to them the contents inside of all the divs are affected, shrinking.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LFen7Qx I'm so sorry. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: By snippet I meant setting up a codepen. I can see the image and understand what u want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atog0Lfj/1/ here I deleted some unnecessary codes

Comment: I deleted all your custom css and added me-2 class to all the direct children of nav. seems to work. Can u check and tell? Bootstrap already has all the css in classes. You should adjust in the HTML file first and then choose external css later.

Comment: It's still the same.... all the divs are now stuck to each other

Comment: yes after removing all are stuck. But after adding me class there is a gap

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atog0Lfj/1/#&togetherjs=72cwG0Tl8m can you show me live?